# How do I run integration tests in only lower lane environment?

Tags: java, spring

What would be the best way of going about it?

I am thinking of creating a scheduled API which will run all integration tests present in the project daily at a specified time. If I were to go for this route, can anyone point me out how I can write an endpoint that will pick up only integration tests to run in LLE and not in Prod?

I suppose for this I will have to make sure all integration tests files are ending with `IntegrationTest.java` and will have to write a code to check for files ending with this name?

Comment: I can't find much about this question that I understand.  Do you want to know how to execute your integration tests against an environment, vis-a-vis a Spring profile-driven test?

Comment: I think the right way is: make use of junit test framework and setup pipeline in Jenkins to run it.

Comment: What are you using to write your integration tests? In JUnit 5 you could use Tags https://www.baeldung.com/junit-filtering-tests. In JUnit 4 the same concept is called Categories. How to run tests for an specific Tag is described in the same link ;)

Comment: in maven (the naming convention (suffix) is already super), "we" have an extra "life cycle phase" and a plugin ([maven-failsafe-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/index.html) ..very similar to "unit"/surefire) (exactly) for this purpose...in gradle "they" :) have similar https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests)